# PHP Laravel extending the error handler class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to build a specific error "stack" for my applications. I have a small module system in place, and I want to be able to add the error handlers from the module to the current error stack. However, there are some error handlers that I want to be checked before the module error handlers, but those need registered before the module error handlers, in case there is in error in the module's bootstrapping process.

The stack I'm going for looks like:

- Logging Error handlers
- Alert Error handlers (firing off emails to developers if necessary)
- Module error handlers
- Application error handlers
- Default fallbacks

When the application starts, the logging, alert, and default fallbacks are placed on the stack immediately. I want to be able to stub the application error handlers in next, and then the module error handlers once the module is determined and loaded. As far as I can see, error handlers can only be placed on the top or bottom of the stack; not inserted in the middle.

Is there a way to insert into the error handler? If not, is there a way to register a different error handling class (one extended from the built-in one)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the interest of time, I managed to come up with a solution that works. It's not what I was really looking for, but I'll share it in case anyone else needs to do something like this.

My approach was to extend the **Illuminate\Foundation\Application** and override the **registerExceptionProvider()** method to register my own **ExceptionServiceProvider**. This provider extends from **Illuminate\Exception\ExceptionServiceProvider** and overrides the **registerHandler()** method. In there, I register my **Handler** in the same manner the original provider registers the default handler.

I added **insert*** versions of each of the error methods provided by the default **Application** and an **insertError** method to the **Handler** that does the actual insert into the error handler stack. Lastly, I altered the start.php file to create my **Application** instead of the default one.

As I mentioned, I don't really like this approach; I feel it's more heavy lifting that what should have to be done. It seems like Laravel should have a better way to extend the actual error handler, or at least an interface to order the error handlers being registered more precisely.